# Magit: Can I reverse a hunk from a previous commit?

Tags: git, emacs, magit

If i'm looking at the log messages and select one specific commit to view the diff is it possible to revert (or reverse appply) a specific hunk of that commit? I know there is a revert commit option but i'm only interested in one small part of it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, and it's the same key-binding whether it's a commit, a file, a hunk, or a marked region.  Just type <kbd>v</kbd> with the thing in question highlighted, and Magit will prompt you accordingly.

Comment: it is `magit-revert` for those with non default bindings ;)

Comment: @xeruf Actually, it is `magit-reverse` and not `magit-revert`.